# Using NOT EXISTS query to INSERT unique customer IDs violates primary key constraint

Tags: ssms, insert-into, sql-server-2014-express, not-exists

I've identified a list of IDs that appear in a `Transactions` table that aren't in the customer accounts table. I've achieved this with the following query which returns approximately 14,000 rows:

```
select SurrID
from tblTransactions t
where not exists (select *
                  from tblCustomerAccounts ca
                  where t.SurrID = ca.SurrID)
```

However, when I then prefix this query with an `INSRT INTO` statement, to append my customer accounts table, I get a primary key violation. For clarity, this is my `INSERT` query:

```
insert into tblCustomerAccounts(SurrID)
    select SurrID
    from tblTransactions t
    where not exists (select *
                      from tblCustomerAccounts ca
                      where t.SurrID = ca.SurrID)
```

This is the error message:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblCustomerAccounts_SurrID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblCustomerAccounts'. The duplicate key value is (2205784830001).
```

The primary key in the customer accounts table is just on the `SurrID` column (not a composite key).  When I've searched for the duplicate key value in the customer accounts table, it doesn't exist.

From what I understand, my original query should show me all SurrIDs in the `Transactions` table that do not exist within the customer accounts table.  Therefore, the `INSERT` statement should append those missing SurrIDs to the customer accounts table. Is my understanding of these queries incorrect or could there be something else going on?

Comment: Is the Transactions table unique on SurrID, too?

Comment: No.  Each `SurrID` will appear multiple times in the `transactions` table.

Comment: And you want to insert them all, including the duplicates.

Comment: No.  I'm trying to insert those `SurrIDs` from the transactions table that aren't currently in the `Customer Accounts` table.  That's what I'm trying to achieve with the `NOT EXISTS` method.

Comment: Well, that is not how it works. At the moment of selection *in the subquery*, the target record doesn't exist for either of the duplicates. (you probably want  `SELECT DISTINCT ... ` here )

Comment: @joop, your question lead me to the solution (that I seem to have come to as you were posting your final comment).  Good questioning!

Comment: You should think of subqueries as *table expressions*; everything in `(select ...)` is just a set of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake!  Needed to include `Distinct` in the select line.  For the benefit of those of us that aren't seasoned professionals, the query I needed is:

```
insert into tblCustomerAccounts(SurrID)
select Distinct SurrID
from tblTransactions t
where not exists (
                    select *
                    from tblCustomerAccounts ca
                    where t.SurrID = ca.SurrID
                )
```